# '...DataType' does not contain a definition for 'Email'

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm using Identity, and the IdentityUsers properties are the next: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.identity.entityframework.identityuser_properties%28v=vs.108%29.aspx
Well, the problem is I have in the AspNetUsers table "Email" and "PasswordHash", but appears the error`'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DataType' does not contain a definition for 'Email' and 'PasswordHash')`
if I put "Datatype.Email" instead of "DataType.EmailAddress" and "DataType.PasswordHash" instead of "DataTtype.Password".

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Email)]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The password must have at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.PasswordHash)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.PasswordHash)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Different passwords.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is telling you exactly what you need. DataType is an enumeration which only allows specific values. These in turn are used for validation in the MVC world to ensure that you have a valid EmailAddress in the field, whatever it happens to be called.

```
[DataType(DataType.Email)] // Not Valid
[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)] // Valid
[DataType(DataType.PasswordHash)] // Not Valid
[DataType(DataType.Password)] // Valid
```

For the full list of valid values, see Intellisense or this URL: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.datatype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Ok! But then what's the difference between the IdentityUser and the DataType properties? I'm creating  an account with Identity, but you are saying I should use these properties (not the IdentityUser properties).

Comment: These are for your UI validation of your ViewModel, whereas the IdentityUser is the DataModel object that gets saved to the DB. The IdentityUser.Email is the Property/DbField that will be in the database, whereas the DataType.Email is how that field is validated in the UI.

Comment: The same and different name. I don't understand the logic. Well, answer accepted.